# Assembler basic question : translation to machine code

Tags: binary, compiler, assembler

How does a assembler (at very basic level) work in translation of Assembly language to machine code ?

[What my understanding  is that when a Programme is written it is written in text and then assembler converts these "texts" into bits which computer understands . So for example if I wrote MOV A, B  this will be saved in memory with the help of "keyboard"( in 0s & 1s which are basically electrical pulses). Now as these  saved bits will be containing bits corresponding to  alphabets like 'M' ,'O' 'V' (The ASCII code) so and so on .Now what assembler will do is to compare these bits stored in the memory ( which are corresponding to the "texts") to the bits already stored in "assembler". So the text bits ( MOV…)  will match to some of these assembler bits ( out of lots of bit groups  which are related to other key words like MVI ,ADD ) and as a result of these comparisons it will give "opcode" relating to “MOV” text. Am  I right or is this a wrong way of thinking? ]

Comment: Go to Antoine VIGNAU and Olivier ZARDINI's web site and read the pages there as well as download their source code. That assembler source is fully available, is relatively simple, supports relocatable objects, and does all the needed linking steps as well. It's all-in-one. Can't beat that. Reading the code will answer all your questions. See: http://www.brutaldeluxe.fr/products/crossdevtools/merlin/ (go to very bottom of page for icon to use.) Or visit: http://www.infinitefactors.org/jonk/patch.html for a modified version of it.

Comment: Example: when I type MOV A, B in RAM :'M' >> some bytes (ASCII CODE) in memory (RAM)in form of 0v and 5v (voltage may be different but you know what I mean) 'O' will be saved same & so V , A , "," , B .Now the programming software also have the part in RAM which we call "library" saved in 0s & 1s in the form of 0v /5v.So my question is that does "translation" mean that typed the 0s,1s of MOV A,B will be compared to saved 0s and 1s (library's)by logic ckt & then depending on the matching or mismatching of those 0s,1s will result in another 0s,1s (opcodes,will be stored & executed in RAM)? @jonk

Comment: An assembler just processes tokens and generates files. Sometimes these are object files. Sometimes they are binary files. Depends on what you want to do. Either way, they are just "data." A different device entirely reads up a binary file, for example, and transfers that data into a hardware device (like a ROM or the flash memory of a microcontroller.) How that is achieved depends on the device. Some devices require 12 or 13 volts to write data, even though they operate normally at 5 V. Other than that, I'm not sure where your head it at so it is hard to know what to add.

Comment: I just want to get insight in what actually happens in RAM when people say that " Assembler translates the assembly language to machine language" at circuit level in simple words .It may not be very technical but logical .

Comment: Without the technical verbage, and avoiding fancy features, "the assembler converts source code into a sequential series of byte values, of length N bytes, that are transferred into some memory starting at some address and continuing for N memory bytes."

Answer (score 1):

The "conversion" between the user-typed text file (assembly code) and the actual binary (executable) code is done by a special program, called an assembler.

It is a text parser, that parses all text in pieces (e.g., first `MOV`, then its operands/arguments). One by one it is translated (items may be stored if needed).

Parses are based on rules, so e.g., if "M", "O", "V" is found in a text file, it knows it has to be translated to e.g., opcode 0x40. Also, it knows what to expect afterwards (arguments). If these are correct those arguments will be translated, otherwise an error message will be shown.

Other settings affecting the resulting binary code.

Update (according to comment):

Steps:

1. The user creates with a text editor the assembly code in text form (e.g., with commands as text like `MOV EAX, 1`, `SUB` ...).
2. This is saved to a hard drive (e.g., disk, or solid-state) as a file (e.g., program.asm).
3. The user runs an assembler program (e.g., nasm.exe).
4. This program reads a file (program.asm) to ram.
5. It translates word by word and operand by operand the text using a parser. The text is translated into opcodes and operands.
6. Sometimes there is an optimization step that removes unnecessary opcodes or changes them into better/faster ones.
7. These opcodes and operands are stored in another file, e.g., program.exe (the executable).
8. When running the program, the program.exe file is read into ram.
9. If there is an operating system, it checks to make sure the program can run, and translates if it is in a portable format (e.g., pe, or elf).
10. The computer/microcontroller executes the code in memory.

Comment: it looks like my understanding written with question is correct. Is it?  :P

Comment: Yes, except that normally it's not in bit level, but bytes, or actually 'text' characters are read and translated into opcodes. 
The assembler creates an executable file, which is stored in memory and executed instruction by instruction.

Comment: I think "read and translation" is confusing to me because assembler is just replacing  certain bits/bytes saved in memory ( ASCII code of English typed  texts when we programme) by the bits/btyes (opcodes) which will work in computer.

Comment: Actually it does not matter much if it is saved into memory or a file on disk for the translation.

I try to add it in my answer

Comment: I know that the edit you made in your answer should've cleared all the doubts for a knowing person. But sir I am beginner to computer organization and architecture + programming languages. I don't know parsing ( although I got little feeling about that) also "translation"  word confuses me every time .I think I just want to know that what happens in the memory (RAM) from when I start writing something on my "programming software".  1/2

Comment: Example: when I type  MOV A, B in RAM :'M' >> some bytes (ASCII CODE) in memory (RAM)in form of 0v and 5v (voltage may be different but you know what I mean) 'O' will be saved  same & so V , A , "," , B .Now the programming software also have the part in RAM which we call "library" saved in 0s & 1s in the form of 0v /5v.So my question is that does "translation" mean that typed the 0s,1s of MOV A,B will be compared to saved 0s and 1s (library's)by logic ckt & then depending on the matching or mismatching of those 0s,1s will result in another 0s,1s (opcodes,will be stored & executed in RAM)?2/2

Comment: I don't know if  I understand what you say ... maybe it is best if you first try to see the difference between an editor (where you type in the program and saves it to a file or files), a compiler (which changes the readable text into machine opcodes, which is essentially a parser) and running a program (executing it). The editor can work on a different platform (like a PC) than the execute (microcontroller). In this case the compiler is called a cross-compiler.

Comment: Every running program is (essentially) run from RAM, this means the execute, the editor, the compiler. And RAM is physically built up from bits, which are internally handled as 0 for 0V 1 for higher (1.8 V, 3.3V or 5V etc). The compiler has no notice of 0V and 5V for example, this is handled by the CPU/microcontroller and the surrounding hardware.